# How to stay on same page after saving partial view

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I have an ajax request for a partial view working fine and gets the information i need for the user to edit, now when the user presses the save button the data saves but it it keeps redirecting to CameraInfo/Index which doesnt exist, is it possible to save and stay on the same page? or even return to the home page if it isnt possible? below is the method involded in the HTTP Post and get code involved

AJAX

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#qr-number').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "Get",
                url: '/CameraInfo/Edit',
                data: { id: $('#qr-number').val() },
                success: function (response) {
                    $('#Sample').html(response);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    if (response.responseText != "") {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                        alert("Some thing wrong..");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

_CameraInfo.cshtml (partial view)

```
@model JobTracker.Models.Job


<h2>Edit and Confirm</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Job</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JobID)

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.OrderID)

  <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LocationID, "Location")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("LocationID", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LocationID)
    </div><br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HighPriority)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HighPriority, new SelectList(
    new[] 
    { 
        new { Value = "Yes", Text = "Yes" },
        new { Value = "No", Text = "No" },
    },
     "Value",
     "Text",
    Model
))

        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HighPriority)
    </div><br />

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comments)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Comments)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comments)
    </div><br />

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Status)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
           @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Status, new SelectList(
    new[] 
    { 
        new { Value = "In Progress", Text = "In Progress" },
        new { Value = "Completed", Text = "Completed" },
        new { Value = "Not Started", Text = "Not Started" },
        new { Value = "Stopped", Text = "Stopped" },
    },
     "Value",
     "Text",
    Model
))
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Status)
    </div><br />

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

}

CameraInfo.cs

```
       [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
    {
        Job job = db.Jobs.Find(id);

        ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "LocationName", job.LocationID);


        return PartialView("_CameraInfo", job);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Job job)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var LastUpdated = System.DateTime.Now;
            job.LastUpdated = LastUpdated;
            db.Entry(job).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        ViewBag.LocationID = new SelectList(db.Locations, "LocationID", "LocationName", job.LocationID);

        return View(job);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is an AJAX call, the user is not supposed to be navigating. It is very likely that the offending code is in the view, possibly a form that is POSTing to the URL instead of performing an AJAX call?

EDIT: Now that you've shown the View code, my suspicions are confirmed. You should not use a regular form, since that will make the user navigate when POSTing the values. An alternative to this is using AjaxForms instead of regular forms. Another one is preventing the form from submitting and rather submitting the values yourself through JavaScript.

I'd actually advice on that last one: using JavaScript to submit, but keeping the form. As such, if someone in your target audience could have JavaScript disabled, you could design around that by using the regular POSTs and user navigations. If they do, you can avoid the navigation by returning false on the submit event of the form.

Comment: i ll add the rest of the code involved in the question if thats the case

Comment: @goldeneye I updated my answer to reflect your scenario -- hope it is useful!

Comment: Thanks @Alpha, just a small question, say i wanted it to navigate and bring up a fresh new version of the current view, would i still need to change it to save via javascript? or can i keep what i have ?

Comment: @goldeneye No, in that case the best approach is to have the POST return a redirect action, which would take you back to the complete view (not the partial view). You don't need any AJAX in that case.

Comment: even after changing the return view, it still seems to redirect to CameraInfo/index which doesnt exist, what section of code do i need to change to alter the path?

Comment: In the httpPost (Edit) action, you should change the `return View(job);` for `return RedirectToAction("YourActionNameHere")`. I'm guessing this will not be the GET /Edit action, because that's supposed to be a partial, so you actually should have another action for the whole view.

Comment: thanks Alpha :) worked fine for time being :) ill look and learn AJAX.beginform later to see about saving the partial view then fade it after its completed